# In Visual Studio Code: How can I find the key of any command?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

There's a command in `Project Manager` extension that opens the project in a new window.
[image: VScode Action]

I'd like to add a key binding to this action but I couldn't find the key to add a binding to.
Is there a generic way to find the key of the last command run? That would be the *"Teach a man to fish"* solution for me.
If you just know the key, that would be the *fish* :) But it's better than going hungry.

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go to `File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts`
- Click `Define Keybinding` to create a new entry
- Go to the `command` entry and start typing the name of the extension. In this case *ProjectManager*. Code completion will show up and suggest all commands which belong to this extension*
  [image]
- Select the one you want to bind and save the file to activate the new shortcut

*Note: You can find a list of all available commands also at the bottom of the left tab named "Default Keyboard Shortcuts"*

**Alternative way: Get a list of all commands for an extension**

- Click on the extensions icon in the sidebar
- Select the extension
- Click on the *Contributions* tab
- A list of all contribution points including *Commands* are shown [image]

Comment: very very nice! Thanks!